# dplyr piping produces different results than base R syntax utilizing same code

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm performing an academic exercise that demonstrates an issue with my understanding of dplyr. Let me reconstruct the iris data set using base-R syntax:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(iris[1], iris[-1])
```

OK, great that works. Now, I'll pipe everything with dplyr - and - it doubles every column in the iris data set. Shouldn't these two pieces of code produce identical results?

```
iris %>% bind_cols(.[1], .[-1])
```

Comment: If you do anything to `.` like subset it, it will still be passed as the first parameter, like the second example above. If you pass `.` unaltered to a parameter, it will only be passed to that parameter, e.g. `100 %>% rnorm(10, mean = .)`. If you want to keep it from being passed to the first parameter, wrap the expression in braces, e.g. `iris %>% {bind_cols(.[1], .[-1])}` and it will only be passed where specified by `.`.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following. `iris %>% bind_cols(.[1], .[-1])` is the same as `bind_cols(iris, iris[1], iris[-1])` because the first argument of `bind_cols` is the one before `%>%`. So the result makes sense to me.

```
aa <- iris %>% bind_cols(.[1], .[-1])

bb <- bind_cols(iris, iris[1], iris[-1])

identical(aa, bb)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice. And `iris %>% {bind_cols(.[1], .[-1])}` would produce same as `bind_cols(iris[1], iris[-1])`.

Comment: @Tino Thanks for sharing. I did not know the use of `{` before.

Comment: I find it useful when I want to plot something but also print a table based on same data: `df %T>% {print(ggplot() + ...)} %>% ...`, where `%T>%` is that fancy kind of pipe-split from `magrittr`.